# How to handle mouse moving of ranges event in Excel using C# VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**introduction:** 
I have a class, that represents table column with similar logic:

```
class ColumnWrapper
{
    int _column;
    int _row;
    string _name;
    string _caption;
    Worksheet _worksheet;

    Dictionary<int, string> _values; // <row offset index, value>

    public void Open()
    {
        // ...
        // Connect to server and get values
        // ...

        Range r = _worksheet.Range[_column, _row];
        r.Value2 = _caption;

        foreach (Range item in _values)
        {
            Range r = _worksheet.Range[_column, _row + item.Key];
            r.Value2 = item.Value;
        }

        var addressStart = String.Concat(ExcelColumnFromNumber(_column), _row);
        var addressEnd = String.Concat(ExcelColumnFromNumber(_column), (_row + _values.Keys.Max()));

        Range range = _worksheet.Range[addressStart, addressEnd];
        _worksheet.Names.Add(_name, )
    }

    public void Delete(string value)
    {
        // Delete row and shift all rows below to up
        int index = _values.First(i => i.Value == value).Key;

        foreach(var key in _values.Where(i => i.Key > index))
            // decrement index

        RefreshValues();
    }
}
```

Users in excel can select some range and then move it somewhere.

[image]

And I need to handle this event, because wants allow to users move only header cells and discard moving in all other cases.

**Secondary question:** how to programmatically move range? Now, on row deletion, I goes through *_values* collection and decrement all indexes, that greater then index of deleted value. After that I reset values for all ranges and it is so slow. But if it will possible to just move range, it will be more faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event out of the box. You can simulate many events by using some additional logic though. I think you could implement the event you need by using the following logic:

1. Subscribe to selection change event.
2. In the event handler you should keep track of the last selected range. You compare it to the currently selected one. If the range values are the same but only the location changed then a move occurred. You then do your logic to determine if only headers were moved. If not you revert the move to the original location.

This should bring you quite close to your solution but you may need to add some additional checks,... Or you might limit this logic to only certain ranges that you do not want to allow to be moved.

As for the second question take a look at [Range.Cut method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838374%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I recorded a macro of moving a range and this was the code that excel used to move the range.

Also [setting the values of a whole range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) is much faster than looping through the cells and setting the cell values.